# I am getting NaN when I subtract two pandas dataframe columns

Tags: pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a dataframe with several columns, I want to get the difference in time between two of the columns containing time. To start I have converted the two columns to DateTime objects using pd.to_datetime, but when I subtract the two columns and assign the result to the new column ends up with NaN values.

```
ops_data_clean_1.loc['Package committed-time'] = 
pd.to_datetime(ops_data_clean_1['Package committed-time'])
ops_data_clean_1.loc['Flight launched-time'] = 
pd.to_datetime(ops_data_clean_1['Flight launched-time'])
ops_data_clean_1['time_to_launch'] = ops_data_clean_1.loc['Flight 
launched-time'] - ops_data_clean_1.loc['Package committed-time']
ops_data_clean_1.head()
```

Comment: Can you please put the code you are using?

Comment: Provide sample data and expected output.

Comment: @Noki just did...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is usage of `loc` when you are accessing just a column from the dataframe. You can eliminate the problem just by removing `loc` from the code.

See the following toy example,

```
ops_data_clean_1 = pd.DataFrame()

ops_data_clean_1['Package committed-time'] = ['2018-01-01 00:00:30', '2018-01-01 00:49:00', '2018-03-01 00:00:45']
ops_data_clean_1['Flight launched-time'] = ['2018-01-01 01:00:30', '2018-01-01 02:49:00', '2018-03-01 00:54:45']

ops_data_clean_1['Package committed-time'] = pd.to_datetime(ops_data_clean_1['Package committed-time'])
ops_data_clean_1['Flight launched-time'] = pd.to_datetime(ops_data_clean_1['Flight launched-time'])

ops_data_clean_1['time_to_launch'] = ops_data_clean_1['Flight launched-time'] - ops_data_clean_1['Package committed-time']

ops_data_clean_1.head()

# Output

Package committed-time  Flight launched-time    time_to_launch
0   2018-01-01 00:00:30 2018-01-01 01:00:30 01:00:00
1   2018-01-01 00:49:00 2018-01-01 02:49:00 02:00:00
2   2018-03-01 00:00:45 2018-03-01 00:54:45 00:54:00
```

If you want to use `loc` you have to select all the rows of the dataframe using `:` For example `ops_data_clean_1.loc[:, 'Flight launched-time']`

Then the code becomes,

```
ops_data_clean_1 = pd.DataFrame()

ops_data_clean_1['Package committed-time'] = ['2018-01-01 00:00:30', '2018-01-01 00:49:00', '2018-03-01 00:00:45']
ops_data_clean_1['Flight launched-time'] = ['2018-01-01 01:00:30', '2018-01-01 02:49:00', '2018-03-01 00:54:45']

ops_data_clean_1.loc[:, 'Package committed-time'] = pd.to_datetime(ops_data_clean_1['Package committed-time'])
ops_data_clean_1.loc[:, 'Flight launched-time'] = pd.to_datetime(ops_data_clean_1['Flight launched-time'])

ops_data_clean_1['time_to_launch'] = ops_data_clean_1.loc[:, 'Flight launched-time'] - ops_data_clean_1.loc[:, 'Package committed-time']

ops_data_clean_1.head()

# Output

    Package committed-time  Flight launched-time    time_to_launch
0   2018-01-01 00:00:30 2018-01-01 01:00:30 01:00:00
1   2018-01-01 00:49:00 2018-01-01 02:49:00 02:00:00
2   2018-03-01 00:00:45 2018-03-01 00:54:45 00:54:00
```

Comment: Nice to hear it helped

Answer (score 1):

I think your trouble lies in .loc function you use.

.loc['Package committed-time'] basically says, select ROWs, which have value 'Package committed-time', which are none.

But you want to select column with that name. Use simple ops_data_clean_1['Package committed-time'] to access the column or ops_data_clean_1.loc[:,'Package committed-time']

More about .loc here: [enter link description here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)